# Can’t remove Schlage door handles

Tags: doors, doorknob

I’ve got a Schlage door handle that I want to remove so I can tighten it since it's loose on the wall, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. All the instructions online talk about these magical little pin holes you press and the handle comes sliding off. Mine has two little holes but pressing on them with nails does nothing. Any ideas?

[image: front door handle]

[image: front door handle pins]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe the nails do not depress the tabs far enough

Comment: Having recently dealt with a similar situation (loose knob), I found that the round portion that is supposed to go against the door needs to be pulled away from the door to expose the screws that need to be tightened. In my case, this thin cover plate was over thicker metal that made up the meat of the knob. I used a flat head screw driver to lever the cover off. I don't know if this is the case with this lock (so I will not add an answer).

Comment: I will also note that my lever had a small hex screw that I could loosen to remove the handle. In your photos, I think I see something aligned with the lever (not the two small holes you highlighted).

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a tiny flat screwdriver and press it into the hole nearest the escutcheon plate. Press it deep into the hole and the handle should pop off.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same one and just dealt with this.  On the inside side of the door handle, place a thick rubber band around the round cover plate and turn counter clockwise with your hands.  The cover will come off, slide it over the handle and two screws will be visible.  Unscrewing these screws will allow removal of the handles on both sides. I know this is from 3 years ago, but I was struggling with the same problem.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to rotate the plate and then slide it onto the handle. If that works, maybe you will see something to help get the handles off.